# LibreOffice OOoBean. How to connect using UNO_PATH from Java app?

Tags: libreoffice, uno

In order to connect to LibreOffice instance, I need to have `UNO_PATH` environment variable set (otherwise, I get `java.io.IOException: UNO_PATH environment variable is not set (required system path to the office program directory)`). If I run my app  from a batch file and set it beforehand, all works fine. However, the best approach would be to read it from the app settings and set it before calling `loadFromURL(...)` method of `OOoBean` object which I use to interact with my Office object.

Does anybody know how to manage to do that? I've been trying different methods including [injection](https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/changing_env_java) even but all of them have failed so far.